# Why is 1000$ called a 'grand'?

Tags: british-english, etymology

Recently I have noticed that people (especially in the USA) call each 1000$ as a '**grand**'.

> "It costs 48 **grand**" = "It costs 48 **thousand** USD"

I have got two related questions about it:

1. Why is it called '**grand**'?
2. How common is the usage of it in the UK?

Comment: My parents here in Yorkshire use the word a lot too. I didn't get it as a child, and to be honest, I still don't get it now.

Comment: Very common in the UK.

Comment: (For 'a thousand pounds', obviously.)

Answer (score 1):

> The term "grand" is American slang from the early 1900s, presumably from the expression "a grand sum of money" to mean $1,000. As with most questions of etymology, we don't know who first used the phrase. The best we can do, in most cases, is to find the earliest written usage, which is around 1915 for "grand."

The usage of it is quite common (for 10 grand anyway) from this Ngram and is increasing:

[image: Ngram]

**It is very common in the UK**.